# Domain Name problems in CentOS hosted under VirtualBox

Tags: centos, iptables, virtualbox

When I `ping www.google.com` I get:

```
[root@ryanPC ~]# ping www.google.com
ping: unknown host www.google.com
```

Also, when I run `ping -n 8.8.8.8`, I get:

`connect: Network is unreachable`

So I have ran the following commands (as root) to disable `iptables` and `ip6tables`:

```
service iptables stop
service iptables save
service iptables status
iptables: Firewall is not running.

service ip6tables stop
service ip6tables save
service ip6tables status
ip6tables: Firewall is not running.
```

I think it will be important to mention that this is being ran on VirtualBox Attached to Bridged Adaptor. My colleague suggested I disable iptables which I did, does anyone else have any suggestions as to what to do?

Update:
So I have followed the article [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolv.conf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolv.conf) that would manually edit the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` file found in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/`. Furthermore, I have ran the command `echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 >> /etc/resolv.conf` But now here is what I am getting:

[image: networkRestart]

Comment: @Christopher: I have updated my question.

Comment: I ran the command, but I do not get any output

Comment: I have no idea why this was downvoted..

Comment: I did not vote on this question, but the question shouldn't be about disabling the firewall, since that's working just fine.  It should be about the problem you're having with resolving domain names.  This question is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Also, to be clear, asking about the firewall is not bad, but you should start with your symptom (unable to ping Google), then explain what you've tried to to do fix it (disable the firewall), rather than the other way around.

Comment: @depquid I have edited my question enourmously..

Comment: What network connectivity do you have in your VM (bridged/NAT/… and other parameters)? Does IP connectivity work: do you get a reply from `ping -n 8.8.8.8`?

Comment: With the information displayed in the screenshot, this appears to be an issue with your VM getting its network configuration from VirtualBox (via DHCP). I've tagged the question with VirtualBox, but I don't use it enough to be able to help.

Comment: @Giles: I updated my question

Comment: I figured out what was wrong!!

Comment: Why was this down-voted?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to change a setting in `VirtualBox`. I had to change my Network Attached from Bridged Network to NAT and after restart I ran an `ifconfig -a` and it finally pulled an IP address!

Comment: It would have been really nice if you had indicated that this was in a VirtualBox type of environment from the start.  Everybody could have convirged on the appropriate solution faster.

Comment: I added I was running this on a VM, I did not think VirtualBox was root cause of this initially.

Comment: The more environment information you provide the better the quality of the resolution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I only ruled this out because I kept flipping between NAT and Bridged Connection multiple times and still couldn't get an IP.

Answer (score 4):

Your firewall is off after you ran those commands. The problem here is DNS setting. You don't have any DNS server to resolve host name `www.google.com`.

A quick fix:

```
echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: I have tried that and restarted network services, but now its unable to determine an IP address. Any Suggestions?

Comment: @ryekayo: Are you sure your machine can access internet.

Comment: i have resolved the problem and was able to use yum installer and wget to confirm connectivity